# How do I translate "candy"?

Tags: word-usage

What is the translation of *candy* in Esperanto? Online, I found many translations, e.g. *kando*, *dolĉaĵo*, and *bombono*. What are the differences between these?

Comment: And there is **frandaĵo**

Comment: Ho, ege interese! Tiun mi ne trovis. Tiu estas ankaux tre gxenerala cxu ne? Povas esti ankaux salgustajxoj.

Comment: Kaj ĝi havas diversajn vortformojn, de frandi ĝis frandemulo, kio ne estas facile esprimebla per aliaj vortoj. Ĝi estas pli ĝenerala, kvankam mia nederlandlingva traduko por frandi = snoepen precipe estas por dolĉaĵoj kiel bombonoj kaj ĉokolado.

Comment: *Frandaĵo* does not refer to candy. Any fine food can be a *frandaĵo*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definitions in [Plena Ilustrita Vortaro](http://vortaro.net) give useful guidance.

I think the best answer is *bombono* for all kinds of small sweet pieces consisting mostly of sugar, chocolate, fruit and other ingredients.

*Dolĉaĵo* (something sweet) is more general. *Bombonoj* are *dolĉaĵoj* but so are sweet pastries and cookies and cakes and even the sweet words you are pouring over your dearest one.

*Kando* and *karamelo* are more specialized words. Both consist essentially of pure sugar.

*Frandaĵo* is anything you consider really good-tasting.

There are certainly differences between different Englishes in the use of words like *candy*, *sweets* and others. But I suppose the useful words in Esperanto are *bombono* and *dolĉaĵo*.

Answer (score 4):

I would use *dolĉajo* to refer to general 'candy' concept. It literally means 'sweet thing'. If you want to say *'I'll buy you some candy for your birthday'* and you go and buy a lot of sweets then you should use *dolĉajo*.

*Kando* is a specific type of candy, *sugar candy* according to Reta Vortaro.

*Bombono* is a small candy, generally involving chocolate. You can see [pictures of 'bombón'](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=candy&biw=1535&bih=1019&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifyMLcuLrPAhXDipAKHdKUAjIQ_AUIBigB&dpr=1#tbm=isch&q=bombon) (the Spanish word) in Google to give you an idea.

Comment: Can't dolcxajxo mean other sweet things too? Like cookies and desserts?

Comment: If you don't need to be too specific you can use it, yes.

Comment: I've always understood "kando" to be the transparent sugar that coats things like candied fruit. The PIV definition is a little more clear than the ReVo definition.

Comment: Pictures meant to illustrate a similar-looking Spanish word don't qualify as an answer when we are talking about words in Esperanto.